# Does Z3 support minimal unsatifiable core?

Tags: z3

Anyone knows does Z3 support `minimal unsatifiable core`? If not, is there any other tool that supports MUC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Z3 does not support minimal unsat core, and to best of my knowledge, there is no smt tools supoorts it. You can implement the algorithm by yourself. There are many papers regarding the algorithm.